# laravel getting error in one to manay relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I am trying to get record(one to many) from database. But it only provides me product table data not both

table structure

[image]

[image]

my model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class brand extends Model
{
protected $table="brand";
 protected $primaryKey = 'brand_id';

public function product(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\product','brand_id','brand_id');
}

}
```

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\brand;

class BrandController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{

   $val=brand::with('product')->find(5)->product;



 foreach($val as $va){

  echo print_r($val);

 }
}
```

It provides me the record from product table but not from both the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching `only` product, remove the product part to get the both:

```
$val=brand::with('product')->find(5);
```

Then to get `brand_name`-

```
$brand_name = $val->brand_name;
foreach($val->product as $product){
     $prod_fault = $product->prod_fault;
}
```

Don't forget as @alexey mezenin said, make your `hasMany()` relation in your `Brand` model like-

```
public function product(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\product','brand_id','brand_id');
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but my relation is one to many and it return 4 record while i have only one record against brand_id(5)

Comment: what do you want to return?? please explain with sample data.

Comment: I am new to laravel i just want to display record from both tables against one id it returning me seperatly like i will run inner loop for other data

Comment: you want to know how to access product data??

Comment: yes i don't know how it will display in the best way

Comment: @SherazKhan please see my updated answer, you will have a idea how to access the data, i just showed for prod_fault and brand_name, you can follow this convention to get other data

Comment: Thank you bro i got the concept

Answer (score 0):

Since brand has many products and product belongs to brand, the relationship must be `hasMany()` and not `belongsTo()`:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\product', 'brand_id', 'brand_id');
```

Comment: still get only product table data

Comment: its not providing me the (brand_name)

Comment: @SherazKhan you didn't ask anything about `brand_name` and it's not related to the question. Just do this to get brand name: `$brand = brand::with('product')->find(5); $brandName = $brand->brand_name;`

Answer (score 0):

Product Model

```
  public function brands()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Brand::class);
    }
```

Brand Model

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

BrandController index method

```
 public function index()
    {

        $brand = Brand::with('product')->find(1);
        echo ($brand);

    }
```

Out Put:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Toyota","product_id":1,"created_at":"2018-02-05 00:00:00","updated_at":"2018-02-05 00:00:00","product":{"id":1,"name":"Car","created_at":"2018-02-05 00:00:00","updated_at":"2018-02-05 00:00:00"}}
```

For further review
[Guide for using Eloquent ORM with laravel by scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel)
Another Link
[Laravel Eloquent Relationships from laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)